# Helm get Values depending on environment

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I want to select different resources limits/requests depending on the environment (which is given as input)

This is my Values.yaml file inside my chart

```
resources:
 dev:
   limits:
     cpu: 100m
     memory: 100Mi
   requests:
     cpu: 20m
     memory: 10Mi
 prod:
   limits:
     cpu: 1000m
     memory: 1000Mi
   requests:
    cpu: 200m
    memory: 100Mi
```

I deploy the chart using this command:

```
helm upgrade --install --values=global_values.yaml
```

and inside global_values.yaml:

```
global:
  environmentSuffix: prod
```

What I want to do is selecting the right resources based on `environmentSuffix` (dev ... prod. 4 environemnts in total)

Something like this (it is not working of course):

```
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: {{ .Values.resources[.Values.global.environmentSuffix].limits.cpu }}
    memory: {{ .Values.resources[.Values.global.environmentSuffix].limits.memory}}
  requests:
    cpu: {{ .Values.resources[.Values.global.environmentSuffix].requests.cpu }}
    memory: {{ .Values.resources[.Values.global.environmentSuffix].requests.memory}}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you fine with if else condition within helm chart?

Comment: @mchawre if it is the only option yes. But we have 4 environments and could be quite verbose to have if-else.

Comment: the best and very simple solution would be to have separate value.yaml file for every env. So just runnng helm install with -f option pointing to correct env-values.yaml should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `index` function from [Go text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) to store the environment resources in a variable and then access it's values.

```
{{ $envResources := index .Values.resources .Values.global.environmentSuffix }}
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: {{ $envResources.limits.cpu }}
```